# TypeError method/function is undefined in the object 'generateGallery' but defined on console.log

Tags: javascript, json, undefined, jqtouch, typeerror

I'm using jQTouch library and the extension photo gallery by http://samshull.com/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqtouch.js"></script>
<script text="type/javascript">
  var jQT = $.jQTouch(...);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jqt.photo.js"></script>
<script text="type/javascript">
  console.log(jQT);
  jQT.generateGallery("galleryID",[{src:"image1.jpg"},{src:"image2.jpg"}]);
</script>
```

When I do a console.log on my jQT object it displays (notice the generateGallery is defined):

```
Object
  addAnimation: function addAnimation(animation) {
  animations: Array[12]
  generateGallery: function generateGallery(id, images, options) {
  getOrientation: function getOrientation() {
  goBack: function goBack() {
  goTo: function goTo(toPage, animation) {
  goToSlide: function (gallery, index, animation, reverse) {
  history: Array[1]
  insertPages: function insertPages(nodes, animation) {
  settings: Object
  submitForm: function submitHandler(e, callback) {
  __proto__: Object
```

but when I try to call `jQT.generateGallery` it says it's undefined.

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'generateGallery'`

Anyone knows what I'm missing here my javascript is a bit rusty.

Comment: @Stephen Ah yes. In fact that's why the `generateGallery` exists. Generally the jQT does not have it when initialised.